# preg_replace non-greedy does not work as I would expect

Tags: php, regex

What I have:

```
 "%g% (%r% %s%)"
```

What I want:

```
"get(%g%)  (get(%r%)  get(%s%))"
```

What I do

```
$zk = "%g% (%r% %s%)";
$pat = '/(%.*%)?/';
$er = 'get($1)';
echo preg_replace($pat, $er, $zk);
```

What I get

```
get(%g% (%r% %s%)get())get()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are being [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) :).

Comment: You need to place the question mark after the quantifier (`*` in this case) for it to be non-greedy. Just a question mark makes it optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negated class based regex:

```
(%[^%]+%)
```

`[^%]+` negated char class which matches any character but not of `%`. So this won't match two `%%` blocks.

OR a non-greedy regex:

```
(%.+?%)
```

Replace the match with `get(\1)`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fT5cX6/5)